# issue in mailable and queue in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am not able pass form data to job from controller in laravel

below is my controller

```
public function sendmail_action(Request $request){
        try{
            $data=$request->all();
            $this->dispatch(new LeadSendmailJob($data));
            return response()->json(['status'=>'true']);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['status'=>'false','msg'=>$e->getMessage()]);
        }

    }
```

below is job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\LeadMail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class LeadSendmailJob implements ShouldQueue

{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data;
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data=$data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      Mail::to('sdf@gmail.com')->send(new LeadMail($this->data));
    }
}
```

and below is mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LeadMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data;
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data=$data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('frontend.emails.lead-mail')
            ->from('info@nextaussietech.com')
            ->with(['message'=>$this->data->message]);
    }
}
```

in failed job table i am getting this exception

ErrorException: Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRM\app\Mail\LeadMail.php:34

it works while using model data but its not working when i am passing form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data` isn't an object, it is an array; `Request::all()` returns an array. You can't access an array with the same notation you would an object.

```
$this->data['message']; // access element of the array
```